# How i will use If.....Else statement in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I need to use If statement before div , if condition met go through the div else go to next condition like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details1";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";

}

@if (Models.Orders_Tables.labCashView.Department_id in (1,2,3,4)) 
{
  <div> 
   // code here 
  </div>
}
else if (Models.Orders_Tables.labCashView.Department_id == 5) 
{
  <div> 
   // code here 
  </div>
}
else if (Models.Orders_Tables.labCashView.Department_id == 6) 
{
  <div> 
   // code here 
  </div>
}
```

The issue when I try to call the Model its not show the model name like this

@if (Model.  here its not show the model name or table name why ?

Comment: And what's the problem? AFAIK C# doesn't have an `in` syntax like that so I suspect that would give you an issue.

Comment: @JLRishe , I dont know this is the idea i looking for to implement this way. to get the data from database depend on department

Comment: This looks right. If Razor thinks your div tag is C#, just put "@:" in front of it, and it will force it to treat it like HTML.

Comment: Moreover there should be `==` for comparison in both `else if` like `Models.Orders_Tables.labCashView.Department_id == 5`.

Comment: @JLRishe The issue when I try to call the Model its not show the model name Orders_Tables or labCashView or column name its not appear  like this

if (Model. here its not show the model name or table name why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like below and it should work.

Here are the changes.

1. Added `var ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` which is used convert your condition to check `in (1,2,3,4)` with `ids.Contains(Models.Orders_Tables.labCashView.Department_id)`
2. Used `==` in both `else if` condition for `compare`.
3. Your `Department_id` might be `int?` that's why you are getting error `cannot convert from int? to int`. Use `GetValueOrDefault()` to retrieve `int` value.

---

```
@model IEnumerable<AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details1";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
    var ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}

@if (ids.Contains(Model.First().labCashView.Department_id.GetValueOrDefault())) 
{
  <div> 
   // code here 
  </div>
}
else if (Model.First().labCashView.Department_id == 5) 
{
  <div> 
   // code here 
  </div>
}
else if (Model.First().labCashView.Department_id == 6) 
{
  <div> 
   // code here 
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I used this after First() i can select tables                                                                                      
 @if (ids.Contains(Model.First().labCashView.DEPTID))                                                            
 but show error   cannot convert from int?   to   int

Comment: Your `Department_id` might be `int?` that's why you are getting error `cannot convert from int? to int`. Use `GetValueOrDefault()` to retrieve `int` value. Updated my answer also with `Model.First()`.